# How to send data from one view controller to other in storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, storyboard

[image]

I am new to storyboard and I am not able to send a data from "Add Filter View Controller" to "Add Filter tableView Controller". Problem is prepareForSegue is not getting called because "Add Filter View Controller" is a root view controller. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Can you show the code that you're using to display `Add Filter Table View Controller`?

Comment: I am not using any code. Just doing everything using storyboard.

Comment: What do you mean that "Add Filter View Controller" is a root view controller? What is its superclass? How are you showing the "Add Filter Table View Controller"? You must share a bit more information. Note that you may want to use embed segues for achieving what you want (based on what you show, which doesn't actually give an idea about possible causes of the problem).

Comment: - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    ICESuppressUnusedVariableWarning(sender);
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"FilterManagerTableviewControllerDoneButtonSegue"]) {
        ICEAddFilterViewController *addFilterVC = [segue destinationViewController];
        [addFilterVC setPositionKeeperCommunicator:[self positionKeeperCommunicator]];
    }
}

Comment: And "Add Filter Table View Controller" is embedded in "Add Filter View Controller"

Comment: @AAV don't post code in comments... edit it into the original question.

Comment: In your `prepareForSegue:`, you can do something like `AddFilterTableViewController *ftvController = [addFilterVC viewControllers][0]` and then pass your data manually that way.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender { 
    AdFilterViewController *destination = segue.destinationViewController;
    destination.dataINeed = self.dataToGive
}
```

where `destination.dataINeed` is a property you need to declare in `AdFilterViewController.h` so this class can interact with it.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Answer from @Kamaros worked.

" In your prepareForSegue:, you can do something like AddFilterTableViewController *ftvController = [addFilterVC viewControllers][0] and then pass your data manually that way"

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you do.

In your `Add Filter Table View Controller.h` file, add a property (whatever is the data you want to pass) :

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *filterList;
```

Then, when you `segue` to that from your `Add Filter View Controller`, in the `Add Filter View Controller.m` file, add :

```
#import "AddFilterViewController.h" //Don't forget to import the destination view controller's header file
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
 {
    AddFilterTableViewController *aFTVC = segue.destinationViewController;
    [aFTVC setFilterList : YOUR_NSMUTABLEARRAY_HERE];
 }
```

I passed an `NSMutableArray` here, but it can be any data type.